# Is it ok to have all Error codes and Messages in a XML file and use that file in the code to Log?

Tags: c#, logging, error-handling

Is it ok to have all Error codes and Messages in a XML file and use that file in the code to Log ??

In this [link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/209693/best-practices-to-create-error-codes-pattern-for-an-enterprise-project-in-c/209720#209720?newreg=364617e4c67b4cd0b304a1ce0f8813fb), in ticked answer he clearly mentioned "Keep a list of all error codes, **but don't do this in your code.** ". I want to know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it ok to have all Error codes and Messages in a XML file and use that file in the code to Log ??

Why shouldn't it?

> Keep a list of all error codes, but don't do this in your code. Keep a short list on a wiki-page for developers, which they can easily edit when they need a new code. The help desk should have a separate list on their own wiki.

Now, that's a different story. People **should not need the source code to look up** the error codes.

Separating the lookup reference lists for help desk and development is yet another story: Development of course needs "bleeding edge" info. But the list will be somewhat volatile.
Help desk will need the "snapshot" list of possible codes for a specific version of the product.

Comment: Is there any advantage of having them in a xml file rather than directly Logging them in the code ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that? Do you mean you'd only log the code?

Comment: If there is a try, catch - Directly Log(Hard code) actual message there in the catch instead of getting the message from xml. What i want to know is Hard code Log there vs Picking Message from xml

Comment: The thing is this: What you log ( = the user gets to see/read) is not always what the helpdesk/developer needs to know. That's why the message is sometimes somewhat useless, but the code will tell the devs what really happened. Also, you can have translated messages. I don't know each language our products are translated to, so ...

Comment: In my case it is not for consumers of my api, it is just for my debug Logging

Comment: In that case, it's up to you. Just logging a code will of course speed up logging itself. On the other hand, reading a message instead of having to look up some code is more convenient ...